# Find if a string can be obtained from a matrix of characters

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic, backtracking

Given a matrix of characters and a string, find whether the string can be obtained from the matrix. From each character in the matrix, we can move up/down/right/left. For example, if the matrix[3][4] is:

```
o f a s
l l q w
z o w k
```

and the string is `follow`, then the function should return true.

The only approach I can think of is a backtracking algorithm that searches whether the word is possible or not. Is there any other faster algorithm to approach this problem?

And suppose I have a lot of queries (on finding whether a word exists or not). Then can there be some preprocessing done to answer the queries faster?

Comment: There are exponentially many possible paths through the grid, so I doubt there's a great preprocessing trick here that will not involve partially enumerating the whole search space.

Comment: And what can you say about answering just single queries in the fastest way.

Comment: Each word will reduce your search space right? like follow, so f should come before o

Comment: Isn't backtracking fast enough?

Comment: Dont know. I think it is. But was just looking for a faster algorithm.

Comment: Are the candidate words coming from a dictionary? Or can they arbitrary strings?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: According to the question, the string is given.

Comment: @MOehm OP mentions that there is not just a single string, many queries may have to be processed.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I read that as queries of many subsequent given strings. If anything, preprocessing will work on the grid, not on the queries.

Comment: @Nikunj Banka: As to "lot of queries": Do you mean 1) Same grid, various strings, 2) Same string, various grids, or 3) various grids, various strings? How big or small can a grid be? How long or short can a string be?

Comment: The candidate words are not coming from a dictionary. 
And for a lot of queries, I mean the same grid and different strings. The size of the grid can be anything. It is not constrained. Same for the string. It would be nice if there is some algorithm that has a nice big-O

Comment: A possible pre-processing step is to enumerate the position of each character in a map or similar structure. So you don't have to find it when the search starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using DFS. Let's define a graph for the problem. The vertices of the graph will comprise of the cell of a combination of cell of the matrix and a length of prefix of the string we are searching for. When we are at a given vertex this will mean that all the characters of the specified prefix were matched so far and that we currently are at the given cell.

We define edges as connecting cells adjacent by a side and doing a "valid" transaction. That is the cell we are going to should be the next in the string we are searching for.

To solve the problem we do a DFS from all cells that contain the first letter of the string and prefix length 1(meaning we've matched this first letter). From there on we continue the search and on each step we compute which are the edges going out of the current position(cell/string prefix length combination). We terminate the first time we reach a prefix of length `L` - the length of the string.

Note that DFS may be considered backtracking but what is more important is to keep track of the nodes in the graph we've already visited. Thus the overall complexity is bound by `N * M * L` where `N` and `M` are the dimensions of the matrix and `L` - the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course find all possible strings (start with a charater and go as far as you can). This can be done with a recursive function.

**grid:**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

**strings:**

```
abcfedghi
abcfehgd
abcfehi
abedghif
abefc
abefighd
abehgd
abehifc
ad...
...
```

Then sort these strings and when looking for a word use a binary search on the list. (When looking for an n letter word you would of course only consider the first n letters of the strings in the list.) A lot of preparation and much memory needed, but searching will be fast. So if you use the same grid again and again, the preparation may finally pay :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the pseudo code for finding if the given string is present in a given matrix. Here visited keeps track of the location of the string in the matrix and it uses backtracking for keeping track of that. I hope this is helpful.

```
bool isSafe(matrix[n][m], int visited[n][m], int i, int j, int n, int m){

if(i<m && j<n && i>=0 && j>=0 && visited[i][j] == 0)
    return true;
return false;
}

bool dfs(char matrix[n][m], int i, int j, int visited[n][m], char str[], int index){

if(index == strlen(str))
    return true;

// row moves
int x[] = {-1, 0, 1, -1};
// col moves
int y[] = {0, -1, 1, 0};

if(str[index] == matrix[i][j]){
    visited[i][j] = 1;
    // for all the neighbours
    for(int k = 0; k<4; k++){
        // mark given position visited
        next_x = i + x[k];
        next_y = j + y[k];

        if(isSafe(matrix, visited, next_x, next_y, n, m)){
            if(dfs(matrix, next_x, next_y, visited, str, index+1) == true)
                return true;
        }
    }
    // backtrack
    visited[i][j] = 0;

}

return false;

}

bool isPresent(char matrix[n][m], char str[]){

// visited initialized to 0
int visited[n][m] = {0};

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(dfs(matrix, i, j, n, m ,visited, str, 0) == true)
            return true;
    }


return false;
}
```