# Finding a sequence of characters in a grid to form a string (moving down or right one step at a time)

Tags: string, algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic

I'm given an n by n grid of characters, and a string s. I want to find a path (sequence of (i, j) pairs in n) such that they form a path that spells out s. I can start anywhere in the grid, but I can only move right or down by one step in the grid.

What's an efficient way of solving this problem? I looked at a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006249/find-if-a-string-can-be-obtained-from-a-matrix-of-characters) where you can move in all directions. But what can we improve from that since we can only move right or down?

Comment: The improvement is that you don't have to keep track of the visited cells, since you can't go round in circles.

Answer (score 0):

First let's define a node in the graph-structure that we're going to use.
For our purposes, a node needs to keep track of its position and the character it represents.

```
static class Node{

    int x;
    int y;
    char c;
    List<Node> adjecent = new ArrayList<>();

    public Node(int x, int y, char c){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

Then we need an easy way to build a grid of nodes, representing our grid of characters.
I've chosen to implement this so that a single String object can represent the entire grid, and a grid can be built from that String.

```
public static Node[][] buildGraph(String s){
    String[] lns = s.split("\n");
    int M = lns.length;
    int N = lns[0].length();
    Node[][] out = new Node[M][N];
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            out[i][j] = new Node(i,j,lns[i].charAt(j));
            if(i != 0)
                out[i-1][j].adjecent.add(out[i][j]);
            if(j != 0)
                out[i][j-1].adjecent.add(out[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Now comes the actual algorithm. Which (as the comments suggested) is based on BFS.
The entrypoint for the recursion is the following method, which checks all nodes in the grid that may serve as valid starting positions.

```
private static void buildWord(Node[][] mtx, String target){
    char c = target.charAt(0);
    for(int i=0;i<mtx.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<mtx.length;j++){
            if(mtx[i][j].c == c){
                List<Node> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
                tmp.add(mtx[i][j]);
                buildWord(mtx[i][j], target, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For each valid starting position, it calls the method 'buildWord' which attempts to find the remainder of the path that would spell the target word.
This is a relatively simple BFS.

```
private static void buildWord(Node start, String target, List<Node> path){
    if(path.size() > target.length()){
        return;
    } else if(path.size() == target.length()){
        String tmp = "";
        for(Node n : path)
            tmp += n.c;
        if(tmp.equals(target)){
            for(int i=0;i<path.size();i++)
                System.out.print("[" + path.get(i).x + ", " + path.get(i).y + "](" + path.get(i).c + ") --> ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    } else {
        char nxtChar = target.charAt(path.size());
        for(Node n : start.adjecent){
            if(n.c == nxtChar){
                path.add(n);
                buildWord(n, target, path);
                path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main method builds a graph from a String, and then attempts to find a path.
The graph being built represents

> abc
>   def
>   ghi

And the algorithm is trying to find the word 'adeh'

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Node[][] matrix = buildGraph("abc\ndef\nghi");
    buildWord(matrix, "adeh");
}
```

It find the path, and prints it

```
[0, 0](a) --> [1, 0](d) --> [1, 1](e) --> [2, 1](h) -->
```